Flink 1.14.3 Batch processing uses TUBLE to prompt exceptions
Hadoop version is 2.6.0-cdh5.16.1 and Flink version is 1.14.3, To gather the number of words To gather the number of words To gather the number of words To gather the number of words To gather the number of words To gather the number of words
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Test> transferStream = mainStream
    .flatMap(new MyFlatMapFunction())
    .returns(Test.class)
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<Test>forBoundedOutOfOrderenter code hereness(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
    .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> DateUtil.parseDefaultNow(event.getBusinessTime()).toEpochSecond() * 1000))

Schema schema = Schema.newBuilder()
    //.columnByExpression("rowTime", "cast(to_timestamp(businessTime, 'yyyyMMddHHmm') as     timestamp_ltz(3))")
    //.watermark("rowTime", "rowTime - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE")
    .columnByMetadata("rowtime", "TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)")
    .watermark("rowtime", "SOURCE_WATERMARK()")
    .column("businessTime", DataTypes.STRING())
    .column("fileName", DataTypes.STRING())
    .build();
tableEnvironment.createTemporaryView("test", transferStream, schema);
TableResult executeSql = tableEnvironment.executeSql("desc test");
executeSql.print();

String sql = "" +
    "select " +
    "       businessTime," +
    "       fileName " +
    "from " +
    "       TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE test, DESCRIPTOR(rowtime), INTERVAL '1' MINUTES)) " +
    "group by " +
    "       window_start," +
    "       window_end," +
    "       businessTime," +
    "       fileName";

desc test result
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+--------+-----------+
|           name |             type | null | key | extras | watermark |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+--------+-----------+
|        rowtime | TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) | true |     |        |           |
|   businessTime |           STRING | true |     |        |           |
|       fileName |           STRING | true |     |        |           |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+--------+-----------+

May I ask why there is no *ROWTIME* mark ? And report the following error
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: SQL validation failed. The window function TUMBLE(TABLE table_name, DESCRIPTOR(timecol), datetime interval[, datetime interval]) requires the timecol is a time attribute type, but is TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE(3).

Both of the above methods have been attempted but have not been successful. How can I run them?
